# Is it expected that sp_core::blake2_256 gives a different result from sp_runtime::traits::BlakeTwo256?

Tags: hash

There are (at least) two different functions for calculating a Blake2 256 hash in the Substrate codebase. More surprising is that they give different hashes for the same message. Is this intended?

Here is a test to reproduce the result

```rust
fn blake_2_256_inconsistency() {
    let message = b"hello world".to_vec();

    let hash_1 = sp_core::H256::from(sp_core::blake2_256(&message));
    let hash_2 = <sp_runtime::traits::BlakeTwo256 as sp_runtime::traits::Hash>::hash_of(&message);

    println!("Hash 1: {:?}", hash_1);
    println!("Hash 2: {:?}", hash_2);

    assert_eq!(hash_1, hash_2);
}
```

The test fails with these hashes printed

```
Hash 1: 0x256c83b297114d201b30179f3f0ef0cace9783622da5974326b436178aeef610
Hash 2: 0x3e4bbda1b5eba20a819aab597b1cc8348248ffd035b2237b788bebe4cc665fa0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fn blake_2_256_inconsistency() {
    let message = b"hello world".to_vec();

    let hash_1 = sp_core::H256::from(sp_core::blake2_256(&message));
    let hash_2 = <sp_runtime::traits::BlakeTwo256 as sp_runtime::traits::Hash>::hash(&message);

    println!("Hash 1: {:?}", hash_1);
    println!("Hash 2: {:?}", hash_2);

    assert_eq!(hash_1, hash_2);
}
```

This will make it work, I changed from `hash_of` to `hash`. If you look at the docs of [`hash_of`](https://docs.rs/sp-runtime/17.0.0/sp_runtime/traits/trait.Hash.html#method.hash_of), you will see that it mentions "Produce the hash of some codec-encodable value.". This means that the value you pass to `hash_of` is first encoded and then hashed. This is the reason why the results are different.